# Erro com "babylon" ao executar npm run dev em projeto Vue

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu

Não sei se realmente tem alguma relação com o problema, mas troquei de sistema ontem, saindo do Windows 7 para o Ubuntu 20.04. No Windows, utilizava o Vue sem problemas. Instalei ele hoje no Ubuntu, mas sempre que tento abrir um localhost, o terminal retorna o seguinte erro:

**`{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.`**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- A versão do Vue instalada é a 4.5.13. Não ocorre erro algum com `vue init`.
- A versão instalada do Node é a 16.9.1. Recebo um aviso de que ele crasha sempre que o erro ocorre, mas é momentâneo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução! Caso alguém precise:

- Siga o caminho `pastaDoProjeto\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\template-compiler` e acesse **index.js**.
- Você provavelmente encontrará o seguinte código:

  ```
    if (!isProduction) {
      code = prettier.format(code, { semi: false, parser: 'babylon' })
    }
  ```
- Simplesmente altere *babylon* para **babel** e salve.

Essa solução funcionou pra mim, espero que funcione pra você também.